# extend the size of already existing ext2 image

Tags: linux, embedded, rootfs

Is there a possibility to extend the size of already existing ext2 image?

This image is a ramdisk based root file system.

I already have an image. but I want to extend the size of this image.

Is it possible to extend the size of this image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely back up before you do this, but it worked for me on a test fs (assuming your disk image is called foo.img):

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=foo.img count=0 bs=1M seek=2000   # assuming target size is 2000M
$ e2fsck -f foo.img
$ resize2fs foo.img
```

Comment: I think the kernel only supports online (mounted) extending for filesystems mounted with `ext3`.